# How to hide header, site Logo, title, side navigation or quick launch bar on SharePoint Page?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm new to sharepoint and trying for an option to hide header, site Logo, title, side navigation or quick launch bar on SharePoint Page. I don't the user to view or access anything except the contents. Can someone suggest please?

Comment: [SharePoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better site for your problem.

Comment: Hi Jyo, You need to provide more information around version of SharePoint etc otherwise this is a broad question